# Linear Dependence on Subdomains of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to utilize the Wronskian to show linear independence of functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$; however, I was wondering how one might show linear independence on restrictions of this domain. For instance the functions $\left\{x^2, 1 - y^2 - z^2 \right\}$ are independent if we consider the space of functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$, but would not be independent if we considered the space of functions on $S^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method (if your subset is particularly nice) is to use a parameterization of the subset.  For instance: the surface $S^2$ is parameterized by
$$
(x,y,z) = \mathbf r(\theta, \phi) = (\sin \phi \cos \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \phi); \qquad \theta \in [0, 2 \pi], \quad\phi \in [0, \pi]
$$
From there, we can say that functions $f,g:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ are linearly independent when restricted to $S^2$ if and only if the functions $f \circ \mathbf r = f(\mathbf r(\theta, \phi))$ and $g \circ \mathbf r$ are linearly independent.  We can consider the Wronskian of these new functions on $2$ variables.

However, it would be nice to have a method for any "smooth surface" of the form $g(x,y,z) = 0$ which doesn't require an explicit parameterization.  I have a hunch that one might be able to do so with a sufficient assumptions on $g$ with a careful application of the chain rule.

Comment: Actually, implicit differentiation might do the trick here in a sense.